# Calculate the sum of a selected row

Tags: c++

I have made a program, which prints out numbers in a form of a shape. 
I want to be able to calculate the sum of a selected row, e.g. I display a shape of 3 rows

```
   1
  1 2
 1 2 3
  1 2    
   1
```

If I wanted to calculate the sum of row 2, it will add `1` and `2` together to show the result.

How would I achieve this?

This is my code so far

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,k=0,n;
    int space = n-1;
    cout << "Enter amount of rows: "; 
    cin >> n;

    while(k <= n)
    {
        for(i = 1; i <= k; i++)
            cout<<i;

        cout<<endl;
        k++;
    }

    k=n;

    while (k)
    {
        k--;
        for (i = 1; i <= k; i++)
            cout<<i;
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the numbers in each row begin with 1 and you know the total number of rows from the input `n`, the sum of numbers in each row can be easily calculated.
You can add the following code after the second `while` loop:

```
int rowNo; //For which the sum has to be calculated
cout << "Enter the row for which the sum has to be calculated" << endl;
cin >> rowNo;

int sum = 0;

int totalRows = n * 2 - 1;
if(rowNo <= totalRows)
{
    if(rowNo > n)
        rowNo = n - rowNo%n; 
    for (int i = 1; i <= rowNo; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    cout << "Sum is " << sum << endl;

}
else
{
    cout << "rowNo: "<<  rowNo << " is greater than the total no of rows: " << totalRows << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I finished my code just before, I didn't see your post until now. 
I basically did what you did there, I tested with your code and works perfectly as well.

Thankyou for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Once you printed all lines, there's no simple way to go back and calculate the sum of the numbers on a specific line.

The simplest way is to calculate the sums of the numbers of *all* lines (as you print them) and store in e.g. a [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Then when you need to get the sum of a specific line just get the pre-calculated sum from the vector.

Comment: I'll give it a try. We learned the basics of C++ around 2 days ago and have an assignment due Sunday.
The lecture didn't cover anything on vectors. I'll see if I can get something to work.
Thanks

Comment: You can also use array of size 2*n-1 to store the sum of a row.

Comment: @Deano Arrays then? Or perhaps ask for the line before you print, and you can then do the sum for only that line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to answer your homework for you but I'd like to give you a few ideas on how to improve your code and how to build a solution that is able to calculate the sum of the desired rows.

Don't simply print your shape when the user entered a number, rather build an object that contains the row information and can be printed.

```
class Shape {
...
private:
  std::vector<Row> rows;

public:
  Shape( int numberOfRows );
  void Print();
...
}
```

A `Row` on the other hand could contain only the information about a single rows content

```
class Row {
...
private:
  std::vector<int> content;  

public:
  void Print();
...
}
```

All you then need is to find implement a way of requesting a single `Row` from the `Shape` and calculate it's sum. The good thing about this way is, that you can easily repeat the 2. step and ask for different rows over and over again.

In your main you would then need to perform the following steps

1. Ask for the the number of rows
2. Create a `Shape` and print it to the screen
3. Ask a user for a row to calculate the sum of (maybe repetitively)
4. Calculate the sum and display it to the user (go back to 3. or exit)

**EDIT:**

I just read that you only had a few basics, so you probably haven't heard about classes yet. So your best bet IMO would be to store the shape in an array ( or an array of arrays ), btw. a [`std::vector<int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) is somewhat similar to a C-Style array ([`int[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array)). Then you can still access the data after you have printed it and calculate the sum of a single row.

Comment: I finished my code just before without seeing this comment, but thanks for helping :)
In the end I did a loop instead of using an array to find the sum